# how to display subtitle in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, objective-c, swiftui, avplayer, subtitle

I want to display subtitle in AVPlayer, but on my code everything is working(video & audio) but subtitle not showing

I tried this answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70938118/17927980

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56251439/17927980

But my player can't display subtitle , how can i fix that?

Is it possible to display subtitle only with AVPlayer or no?

Answer (score 0):

you get your subtitles from an url correct?
Then you need to include the URL to your webVTT subtitles.

It's been a long time since i last take a look at streaming things with AVPLayer, but apple provides an excellent example page for streaming.

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: my subtitle is local and i get the correct url... if i convert my srt to vtt avplayer can display it?